# Different layout for different action controller

Tags: module, customer-account

I created a module that add a link inside customer account navigation. My controller is like this

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function testAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

If I go to /customer/mymodule/index I can see correctly the layout with my own .phtml specified inside the .xml.

Now I would like to assign to customer/mymodule/test another file .phtml with always the left account customer navigation as inside the index action.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a layout.xml for your module

Comment: what is mean by "customer navigation as inside the index action".

Comment: @AmitBera in testAction I want the same layout of indexAction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` layout tag allows you to call another layout handle in your current handle. I suggest that this is what you are looking for. It will allow you to use the exact same layout as in the index action and then make any changes that you need.

```
<your_first_handle>
    <!-- some layout goes here -->
</your_first_handle>

<your_second_handle>
    <update handle="your_first_handle" />
    <!-- any layout for the second handle can go here -->
</your_second_handle>
```